# How does CrimeFlare find the origin ip address of a Cloudflare website?

Tags: security, cloudflare

I am getting a bit into protecting my website but someone keeps posting the origin-ip of my website. I've found out that this website is exposing it: http://www.crimeflare.org:82/cfs.html 
after some extra research I found that this site has been online for a couple years but no info on how it is made or what technique it uses. Does anyone have a clue how this website gets the direct-connection IP address? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I can answer this question. It's really all due to domain history in a nutshell. In order to avoid domain history fetching websites, so-called CloudFlare resolvers and Crimeflare, you need to change your origin IP while under the banner of CloudFlare. Then to stay hidden you MUST not use the email services from your domain otherwise a simple MX record lookup will expose your origin IP. So this means you now need to use third-party email services. If you are using a VPS or bare metal you need to setup IPtables so that ALL IPs are blocked and just allow CloudFlare's IPs. This way IP scanners like Censys can't find your origin IP either since all IPs would be blocked except CloudFlare's forcing all connections to go through CloudFlare. Thankfully CloudFlare IPs don't change that often and they do publish the IP list at their website.

If you are using a shared account you'll want to make sure your shared account uses a shared IP and not a unique IP. With a shared IP your website is mixed with others and these CloudFlare resolver websites can't distinguish between who's who to get your origin IP.

There are some other very minor trivial things to also consider. One trivial possible vector for origin IP exposure is allowing remote content to be published via the website. Be it a remote avatar or file. The link used from this remote content has the possibility of resolving your origin IP behind CloudFlare.

If you are using a shared account you can help block direct IP connections and keep all connections going through CloudFlare in one of two ways. In an Apache or Litespeed SAPI, add the following to your htaccess file:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^$

> RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

What that code does is check for the CloudFlare Geo location header in the request from CloudFlare and if not present the user gets a 403. Thus all connections must go through CloudFlare. In order for this to work, the IP Geo Location option has to be turned on in your CloudFlare dashboard under Network.

The other really unique and awesome way of doing this is by using CloudFlare Workers. You can read about that here:  https://community.cloudflare.com/t/stop-cloudflare-bypassing-on-shared-hosting/91203

I use all of these methods myself with my websites minus the fact of not using a VPS. So far my origin IP is not shown in Crimeflare or other websites.

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

They very much explain it on that very site:

> There are sites on the web that specialize in collecting registration and nameserver data. [..] CloudFlare maintains around 391 nameservers, and customers must change the nameservers on their registration in order to use most services. Each customer's domain is assigned two nameservers. This makes it easier to verify which domains depend on CloudFlare, and helps us keep our domain lists relatively current.

In other words, they look at public nameserver data and filter out the domains that have their nameservers pointed at one of CloudFlare's nameservers.